# Should Router Firewall be deactivated when forwarding ports?

Tags: firewall, router, port, port-forwarding

I'm trying to understand how a router's firewall works when ports are forwarded.  As an example, I have vlc running on an ubuntu server in a remote location.  I've setup VLC to stream content from my surveillance camera in this remote location on port 8080.  In my router, I have forwarded external port 4000 to 8080 (internal).  The firewall on my router is set to "Standard" which by definition, "allows all outgoing connections and blocks all incoming connections".  It's obvious that if someone is forwarding ports, you would expect incoming connections in order to be redirected to a server.  Would this imply that I would have to deactivate the firewall in order for the incoming connection on port 4000 to be forwarded to the respective server? Or by default, would the firewall add all forwarded ports to the list of exceptions?

Comment: "The firewall" does not refer to anything specific device, and could also mean many things from simple stateless packet filters through stateful firewalls to next generation firewalls (NGFW). In general, it is not necessary nor wise to disable the firewall altogether. Instead, you would add rules that matches the desired traffic.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, let's say you have one port forwarded port as in the example in my post.  It's obvious that I'm expecting incoming connections and a corresponding outgoing connection.  What good will enabling the firewall do since all other ports are closed with the exception of the one forwarded port (4000 external => 8080 internal) which I **do** want incoming/outgoing traffic?